# Is it legal for a hostel to write down my debit card information for security purposes?

Tags: united-kingdom, security, debit-card, visa

I just moved to Manchester and I'm staying at a hostel. I booked a bed online via hostelworld.com. What bothers me is that a receptionist asked me to give her my debit card in order to ensure some sort of security. She wrote down the details of my debit card. Is that legal to do so?

Comment: Legal, or within the rules of the credit card processor?  We need a location tag too.  And welcome!

Comment: Yeap, Manchester, United Kingdom

Comment: Alright, is that legal? Cause I am afraid that someone can use my debit card details for bad; steal money from me. In fact, I just spent a night at hotel in Bradford, United Kingdom. So, they asked for my debit card too; swaped it once on there till machine.

Comment: You aren't supposed to give your debit card details, because you wouldn't get the fraud protection as available from a credit card. Cancel your debit card or say it is stolen or something. Generally it would have been provided to them from the booking site to confirm your reservation, you shouldn't have been asked to provide it again.

Comment: One more question though, do you use a chip and pin debit card ? Did you provide the CVV number ? If you provided the CVV number too then, I would play safe and cancel the card. But if they do try to take a payment, it would leave a trail for the merchant.

Comment: @DumbCoder what are you talking about? Have you ever stayed at a hotel?

Comment: @littleadv - Snarky as again, read both my comments. I said if you had already provided the details through the booking website, it is little fishy they ask you again. I would believe in a proper hotel all card details isn't shared with everybody working there because of security reasons. And they should have it in their records. I have been bitten once, so stating something to ponder on.

Comment: @DumbCoder well... That's why I asked. Obviously you've never been to a hotel. No travel site will share your credit card with anyone. Moreover, its perfectly reasonable to pay for the hotel with one card, but for incidentals - with another. I don't know who and how bit you, but try to understand that telling a guy in a middle of nowhere on a trip to cancel his debit card is not a really good suggestion. What on Earth for, and what is he going to do after that? Think a little before saying things.

Comment: @littleadv - **No travel site will share your credit card with anyone**. I seriously doubt that. Many prominent travel websites specifically mention they don't hold my credit card details but pass on to the hotel, so that I can be charged if I don't cancel within the specified time limits or for any damage I might have caused during my stay. Regarding cancelling the card that I mentioned so he can be safe. And generally hotels swipe your card, not ask for card details to be provided to them, when you arrive so they have the card details to charge to. What the hotel did maybe legit, but.

Comment: It's a hostel, not a hotel. Hostels are budget places and may act in a less sophisticated manner than a hotel, hence taking details down manually rather than just swiping them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is legal and is a common practice. Hotels take your credit/debit card information in case there are additional charges (incidentals) billed to you during your stay, or to ensure you pay if you didn't pre-pay. Every hotel does it. If they just swiped it - the information is in the computer, but they still keep it.

You might see a pending charge from the hotel on your account. It is an "authorization", not a real charge. You should make sure they cancel it when you leave as to not hold funds on your account tied up unnecessarily.

As to your concerns - when you leave, request to take that note from the reception after you've paid your bill. Debit card transactions without a swiped card and typed-in PIN are considered credit card transactions (except that they're charged to your account immediately) and enjoy the same fraud protections. So unless you've given them your PIN as well (which you should never do), you're OK.